# VueJS functional components (SFC): how to encapsulate code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I wrote a simple template-substitution component in VueJS as a single-file component. It doesn't have many features: just one prop, and I also made a computed property to encapsulate some tricky transformations that are done to that prop before it can be used in the template. It looks something like the following:

```
<template>
  ...some-html-here...
    <a :href="myHref">...</a>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    props: {
      href: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    computed: {
      myHref() {
        let result = this.href;
        // several lines of complicated logic making substitutions and stuff
        // ...
        return result;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Now I think this should really be a functional component, as it has no state, no data, no reactivity, and so lunking around a whole instance is wasteful.

I can make this functional just by adding the 'functional' attribute to my `<template>`. In a functional component, of course, there are no such things as computed properties or methods or whatever. So my question is: where can I put my several lines of complicated logic? I don't want to have to embed this directly into my template, especially as it is used in multiple places. So where can I put code to transform my input props and make them ready to use in my template?

Comment: I have used render functions in these scenarios. If you don't like using the functions syntax, you can also use jsx.

Comment: Good point -- it can certainly be done by switching to a render function. I'm really looking for ways to retain the benefits of a template in markup though.

Answer (score 0):

> Great question.I was trying to find the same answer and i ended up with the following which i don't know if it is a good way to do though.

**The "html" part:**

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <button @click="props.methods.firstMethod">Console Something</button>
    <button @click="props.methods.secondMethod">Alert Something</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**The "js" part:**

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    methods: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {
          firstMethod() {
            console.log('You clicked me')
          },
          secondMethod() {
            alert('You clicked me')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[See it in action here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n9n8ml9olj)

Make sure to read about [functional components at docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components)

**NOTE:** Be aware using this approach since functional components are stateless (no reactive data) and instanceless (no this context).